# Django/Python Runtime Error: RecursionError at /blog/cubs/

Tags: python-3.x, django, recursion, django-models, runtime-error

I have created a website, and I keep getting recursion errors on my /blog/cubs page, I have 2 identical pages for Beavers and Scouts but when I view the cubs equivalent I keep getting this recursion error.

Below is the tracefile:

[pastebin of tracefile as it's too large to post here](https://pastebin.com/YyBbtMzZ)

Here is the urlpatterns variable from cubs/urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostList.as_view(), name='cubs_blog_home'),
    path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='cubs_blog_about'),
    path('search/', views.SearchView.as_view(), name='cubs_blog_search'),
    path('file_upload/', views.upload, name='cubs_blog_file_upload'),
    path('downloads/', views.DownloadView.as_view(), name='cubs_blog_downloads'),
    path('badge_placement', views.BadgePlacementView.as_view(), name='cubs_blog_badge_placement'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostList.as_view(), name='cubs_blog_user_posts'),
    path('post/new_post/', PostCreate.as_view(), name='cubs_blog_post_create'),
    path('post/<slug:slug>/like/', views.PostLikeView, name='cubs_blog_post_like'),
    path('post/<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='cubs_blog_post_detail'),
    path('post/update/<slug:slug>/', PostUpdate.as_view(), name='cubs_blog_post_update'),
    path('post/delete/<slug:slug>/', PostDelete.as_view(), name='cubs_blog_post_delete'),
    #path('posts/<int:year>/<int:month>/', main_website_views.CubsPostMonthArchiveView.as_view(month_format='%m'), name="cubs_blog_post_archive_month"),
    #path('post/tag/<slug:slug>/', views.tagged, name="cubs_blog_post_tags"),
]
```

And this is my woodhall_website/urls.py file:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/beavers/', include('beavers.urls')),
    path('blog/cubs/', include('cubs.urls')),
    path('blog/scouts/', include('scouts.urls')),
    path('executive/', include('executive.urls')),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('', include('main_website.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    path('admin/password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='admin_password_reset'),
    path('admin/password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset.html'), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Comment: I assume that you already closed `urlpatterns` list with closing `]` which I edited.

Comment: yes i did, everything is working apart from this specific part @SunderamDubey

Comment: Can you add the `Article` model and the `PostList` view code

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `{% endfor %}` in `latest_news.html` .

```
{% block content %}
   2 : <div class="content-section">
   3 :     <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
   4 :         <h2>Latest News</h2>
   5 :         {% for article in articles %}
   6 :         <div class="list-group-item rounded-sm">
   7 :             <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
   8 :                 <h5 class="mb-1">{{ article.article_name }}</h5>
   9 :                 <small> {{ article.date_posted }} </small>
   10 :             </div>
   11 :             {% for tag in article.tags.all %}
   12 :                 <a href="{% url 'main_website_article_tags' tag.slug %}" class="mr-1 badge badge-pill badge-info">{{ tag }}</a>
   13 :             {% endfor %}
   14 :             <hr class="my-1">
   15 :             <a href="{% url 'main_website_article_detail' article.slug  %}" class="btn btn-custom-green btn-sm mt-1 mb-1"><i class="fa-duotone fa-book-open-reader"></i> Read More</a>
   16 :         </div>
   17 :         {% empty %}
   18 :         <div class="list-group-item rounded-sm">
   19 :             <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
   20 : {% endfor %}
```